How do I disable the wireframe on the boolean modifier in edit mode?
In Object Mode, the boolean hides what I want to hide, but in Edit Mode, the part of the mesh that I want to hide appears as a wireframe and makes it harder to work on my model. How do I disable that wireframe?

Please add some images so that we can see what you are asking. Blender has a built-in screenshot facility from its Window > Save Screenshot menu and you can then edit your question and add them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post
